# Adding JAR to eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am trying to use JTidy on google app engine. In Eclipse, I add JTidy jar to the build path and add the jar again as the source attachment.  When I make a tidy object it shows up as a org.w3c.tidy.Tidy.  but when I run my app i get the error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/tidy/Tidy.  Am I not adding the jar correctly?  Does JTidy not work on google app engine?

Comment: how do you upload your application to the appengine?

Comment: I use the deploy button, but I have the problem in debug on my local host as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JAR needs to be added to the lib folder in war/WEB-INF

Answer (score 0):

Add the jar to war/WEB-INF/lib  and also right-click on the project, configure build path. Their add external libraries.